# Class 'App\' not found on laravel 5.2

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I want to add data to the database after a successful validation,but i get this error.'

```
     FatalThrowableError in AboutController.php line 51:
     Class 'App\About' not found.
```

**My Controller**

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\About;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    class AboutController extends Controller
    {


public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $about = $request->about;
        $validation = \Validator::make($about, About::$rules);
        if($validation->passes())
        {
            About::create($about);
            return route('about/admin')->compact(about);
        }  



    }
```

**my Model**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class About extends Model
{
    //
   protected $guarded = array('id');
   protected $fillable = array('about');

   public static $rules = array('about' => 'required|5');
}
```

location of controllers and Model:

```
App\Http\Controllers\AboutController
App\About
```

I have tried to run

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

I'm stuck can anyone tell me what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @webNeat said you should change the namespace that you are using in your Model.

**Your Model About**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class About extends Model
{
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\About; // You have declared App\Http\Controllers in your Model
```

**Model About Fixed**

```
<?php
namespace App; // change to this namespace
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class About extends Model
{
```

If you're a bit lost with Laravel or namespaces I strongly recommend you to use php artisan with each of its commands, and see and study what they do by reading all the code generated. For this case with:

```
php artisan make:model About
```

You will get a fresh new About model prepared for receive all your code with the correct namespace.

Answer (score 2):

changing the namespace of your model to `App` should fix the issue.

```
<?php
namespace App; // <- here
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class About extends Model
{
```